# 2D array minimum sum of Y elements and just two rows that we can chose to get minimum

Tags: arrays

With given 2d array[X][Y], i have to find the smallest possible sum of Y elements but:

> the sum must be created by using just 2 rows,
>   each value must be from different index

Example:
for array

`7  3  7 9
2 20 10 6
8  8  8 8`

Result should be 18, as we get 3 + 7 from 1st row and 2 + 6 from 2nd.

I've been thinking about few hours but i can't figure out how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-sum-submatrix-given-2d-array/).

> Method 1 (Naive Approach): Check every possible submatrix in given 2D
>   array. This solution requires 4 nested loops and time complexity of
>   this solution would be O(n^4).
>
> Method 2 (Efficient Approach): Kadane’s algorithm for 1D array can be
>   used to reduce the time complexity to O(n^3).